# How do I write a jQuery plugin that is called like `$.myplugin.func()`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've written a simple jQuery plugin, but I'd like to make it more advanced so I can do things like:

```
$.myplugin.close();
$.myplugin.open();
$.myplugin.next();
$.myplugin.prev();
```

How can I write a plugin that can be called like this?

-------------------------Updated-------------------------

Thanks @Craig MacGregor, appreciate it.

But to call the function it need to be like below

```
$(this).myplugin.load();
```

Comment: This is bad format and should never be built like this. All functions should be accessed as methods, like $('ele').myplugin('close/open/next/prev');

Comment: @Ohgodwhy if i need set my options to be more in detail then i need to write as 
' $('.ele').myplugin({action:'close',xxx:xxx......}); '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign an object to "myplugin" like so:

```
$.myplugin = {
  close: function(){ 
      //code
  },
  open: function(){
      //code
  },
  next: function(){
      //code
  },

  prev: function(){
      //code
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

***Just An Example:***

```
(funciton($) {
  var methods = {
    init: function() {},
    close: function() {},
    open: function() {},
    prev: function() {},
    next: function() {},
  };

  $.fn.myplugin = function (method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method == 'object' || !method) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on myplugin' );
    }      
  };

}(jQuery));

//usage
$(selector).myplugin();

// call methods
$(selector).myplugin('close');
$(selector).myplugin('open');
$(selector).myplugin('next');
$(selector).myplugin('prev');
```